# Mapping several URLs to one login page

Tags: beginner, .htaccess

My htaccess has this block in it:

```
RewriteRule ^login$ _user/login.php
RewriteRule ^login\.php$ _user/login.php
RewriteRule ^_user/login$ _user/login.php
RewriteRule ^_user/login\.php$ _user/login.php
```

How do I consolidate this block? The objective is to point to `_user/login.php` regardless of where on the server it's called from.

Comment: My only other rules are similar to this aside from a filesmatch and the options. For now I just know I could be doing this better but am a fool when it comes to regex and don't fully understand the syntax of htaccess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The last rule is completely superfluous, but harmless: it just maps the desired URL to itself.

The four cases can be combined into one rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(_user/)?login(\.php)?$ _user/login.php
```

In a regular expression, `(something)?` makes the `something` optional.  That is, whether the URL starts with `_user/` or not, and whether the URL ends with `.php` or not, it will get mapped to the desired login page.

Comment: Thank you! I was trying other things earlier with (.*) but never knew about ? This answer works perfectly but leads me to my next question. I forgot that I always wanted the url to display site/login and hide the subdirectory. Is that just a complicated rewriterule? Sometimes I feel like I'm going in the wrong direction.

Answer (score 2):

Some remarks about the bigger picture:

What is your goal with this? Why are you mapping four differnt urls to the same resource?

It it generally a bad idea to have multiple URLs display the same content. (Google "duplicate content").

Instead you should have all those additional URLs redirect to one canonical URL - if you actually need those additional URLs. You should design your site, so that only one URL is necessary.

Comment: I have the login file called from two different files. In two different folders.
I'll look into canonical URLs. Only one url is necessary, I more or less just want to direct "login" to the login page. [there's no REAL goal]